# Response.Redirect with # anchor, does not work in IE7

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-tabs

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("myprofile.aspx?uid={0}&result=saved#main",user.UserID));
```

said code translates to

**IE7** - `myprofile.aspx?uid=933fdf8e-1be0-4bc2-a269-ac0b01ba4755&result=saved`

**FF**- `myprofile.aspx?uid=933fdf8e-1be0-4bc2-a269-ac0b01ba4755&result=saved#main`

why does IE7 drop my anchor?

edit: I should mention I am using this in conjunction with jQuery UI's tab control.  I want the postback to tab into a specific tab.

Comment: can you verify that IE7 is getting the true URL (e.g. from the HTTP Request) but dropping the hash value? (e.g. do you have Fiddler2 installed (or similar)?)

Comment: scunliffe - I got fiddler2 installed but I'm so new with this tool I couldn't figure out the answer to your question.  however I want to thank you for recommending to me this tool - I had heard of it but you pushed me to actually learn more about it and see its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be quite the hack, but if IE isn't behaving, you could do this.

pass a param as well, e.g.

```
uid=933fdf8e-1be0-4bc2-a269-ac0b01ba4755&result=saved&hash=main#main
```

Then on your page (before the body close tag, or as an onload event), only for IE, extract the parameter if present and set the hash manually.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script>
  if(document.location.href.indexOf('&hash=') != -1){
    //extract value from url...
    document.location.hash = extractedValue;
  }
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: document.location.hash = '<%= Request["hash"] %>'; 

that worked, thank you - changed to code above.

if I server.transfer this - I can hide the url messyness - after all I'm just bouning back for ui updates, do you know if there are any implications to this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a regression issue from IE6?

Did you try [working around it](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/tomphan/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6) by prepending it with an &?

Comment: that didn't work, thanks for the suggestion - the & made it but the # didnt

Answer (score 0):

I used `RegisterClientScriptBlock` to issue `window.location`.

Something like this:

```
string url = String.Format("{0}RegForm.aspx?regId={1}#A", this.CurrentFolderUrl, this.RegId);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "redirectToClientPage", String.Format("window.location='{0}'", url), true);
```